# Would like clarification on the heapq.nlargest parameter 'key'

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, heap

The following function returns the Top k elements in an Array.  It assigns a frequency to each unique element in the Array and adds the data to the `numbers` dictionary.

**numbers:**

```
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1}
```

I am confused about the `heapq.nlargest(k, numbers.keys(), key=numbers.get)` portion; how exactly are the iterable parameter `numbers.keys()` and key parameter `numbers.get` being utilized?

I understand that `heapq.nlargest()` converts `numbers.keys()` to a Max Heap structure, but I am confused on why specifically `numbers.keys()` and not just `numbers`?

Finally, why is the key parameter `numbers.get` the one being used?

```
def topKFrequent(self, nums, k):
    numbers = {}
    for n in nums:
        if n in numbers: numbers[n] += 1
        else: numbers[n] = 1        
    return heapq.nlargest(k, numbers.keys(), key=numbers.get)
```

I am trying to make sense of this:

`heapq.nlargest(n, iterable[, key])`

> Return a list with the n largest elements from the dataset defined by
> iterable. key, if provided, specifies a function of one argument that
> is used to extract a comparison key from each element in the iterable:
> key=str.lower Equivalent to: sorted(iterable, key=key,
> reverse=True)[:n]

Comment: "why specifically `numbers.keys()` and not just `numbers`?" It doesn't matter; both would work just fine, and `.keys()` is just slightly slower (it has to make a view object to iterate the same values). Some people just really like typing more.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I see. how about the ```keys``` parameter? This one seems to require the ```.get``` which returns a dict object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us decompose it:

```
heapq.nlargest(k, numbers.keys(), key=numbers.get)
```

This code will iterate over `numbers.keys()`, so over the keys of the dictionary `numbers`. They will be sorted according to the key function `numbers.get` which returns the value associated to each key.

That means that you will get the keys from `numbers` corresponding to the `k` largest values.

As noted by @ShadowRanger in their comment, you could also use:

```
heapq.nlargest(k, numbers, key=numbers.get)
```

since iterating over a dictionary actualy iterates over its keys.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: thanks a lot for the edit. Looks like I should have my lunch break now...